# how to see the data that was added to an entity in core data

Tags: core-data

Here I am creating a project using core data.when there is a single entity it is working fine.but after,when we add another entity the whole application is crashing.
  And another problem is I am unable to see the data that is added to an entity.is there any way to see those values.help me in this case.

Comment: Please, format your title and question in a more readable way...

Comment: It's possible that by adding new entities to an existing EntityModel you can get an model mismatch error. This occurs if you don't allow your models to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Sqlite as the data store, you can always open the database file with Sqlite Studio and navigate/research your save data as with any other Sqlite database.